# Vertica licence is invalid or has expired

Tags: vertica

I got this error in vertica query this morning:

```
Error: [Vertica][VJDBC](5517) ERROR: Your Vertica license is invalid or has expired
SQLState:  V2001
ErrorCode: 5517
```

After running the command:  `select GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS();`

I got this results:

```
 Raw Data Size: 1.26TB +/- 0.09TB
 License Size : 1.00TB
 Utilization  : 126%
 Audit Time   : 2015-11-05 06:42:23.380593-05
 Compliance Status : ***** NOTICE OF LICENSE NON-COMPLIANCE *****
Continued use of this database is in violation of the current license agreement.
Maximum licensed raw data size: 1.00TB
Current raw data size: 1.26TB
License utilization: 126%
IMMEDIATE ACTION IS REQUIRED, PLEASE CONTACT VERTICA

 No expiration date for a Perpetual license
(1 row)
```

I tried to:
 1. Delete records
 2. Drop redundant schemas
 3. Purge db

And non of them got me to a working vertica with licence.

How can i update the licence or clean more data somehow?
Do you have some advice?

Answer (score 4):

You need to run `SELECT`[`AUDIT_LICENSE_SIZE()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/LicenseManagement/AUDIT_LICENSE_SIZE.htm) to recalculate your database size for compliance purposes.  This normally runs on a schedule, but you haven't hit that time yet since it just happened.  Look at your `Audit Time` on your compliance report.

After running this, you can rerun `SELECT`[`GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/LicenseManagement/GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS.htm) to see where you are at.